# AWS: Automating queries in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, automation, amazon-redshift, etl

I want to automate a redshift insert query to be run every day.

We actually use Aws environment. I was told using lambda is not the right approach. Which is the best ETL process to automate a query in Redshift.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what the query is doing and how long it takes to run? Did they suggest why Lambda was not the right approach?

Comment: Have you looked into Amazon Quicksight for scheduled reports (queries from Redshift)?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein the functionality behind this query is to join few redshift tables like (stl_query, stl_session, stl_ddltext) and load into a custom created table and everyday this query needs to be run.   The reason they said lambda is not the right approach is, it can be active only for 300 seconds and what if my query takes more than 5 mins to run. Pls advice.

Comment: Yes, the 5-minute limit is the important factor. If the query is likely to take longer than 5 minutes, Lambda is not an option.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yea my query won’t take more than 5 mins, but worst if it takes more than 5 then this process will not be suitable. Pls advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For automating SQL on Redshift you have 3 options (at least)

**Simple - cron**
Use a EC2 instance and set up a cron job on that to run your SQL code.

```
psql -U youruser -p 5439 -h hostname_of_redshift -f your_sql_file
```

**Feature rich - Airflow (Recommended)**
If you have a complex schedule to run then it is worth investing time learning and using apache airflow. This also needs to run on a server(ec2) but offers a lot of functionality.

https://airflow.apache.org/

**AWS serverless - AWS data pipeline (NOT Recommended)**

https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/

**Cloudwatch->Lambda->EC2 method described below by John Rotenstein** 
This is a good method when you want to be AWS centric, it will be cheaper than having a dedicated EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks Jon! Not a cron expert so have few questions.. we have a ec2 instance and we can have a cron Job in that. How will my cron job trigger the sql. Should I write a shell script. Pls explain.

Answer (score 2):

One option:

- Use **Amazon CloudWatch Events** on a schedule to trigger an AWS Lambda function
- The **Lambda function** launches an EC2 instance with a User Data script. Configure *Shutdown Behavior* as `Terminate`.
- The **EC2 instance** executes the User Data script
- When the script is complete, it should call `sudo shutdown now -h` to **shutdown and terminate** the instance

The EC2 instance will only be billed **per-second**.

Comment: That's also a valid option. I will add mention of it to my answer above. (I have not used that method myself yet)

Answer (score 2):

Redshift now supports scheduled queries natively: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/query-editor-schedule-query.html

Comment: Note, this doesn't exist in V2 editor. Yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can use boto3 and psycopg2 to run the queries by creating a python script
and scheduling it in cron to be executed daily.

You can also try to convert your queries into Spark jobs and schedule those jobs to run in AWS Glue daily. If you find it difficult, you can also look into Spark SQL and give it a shot. If you are going with Spark SQL, keep in mind the memory usage as Spark SQL is pretty memory intensive.