# what is the best way of ETL Process In AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have my data in redshift cluster and it's refreshing on a daily basis.

I want have to run a SQL code on a daily basis that will create the table in redshift cluster. So I have to setup the ETL job that will run on a particular time to create the table from SQL code.

I have no idea, what is the best way, I am very new in AWS and have good knowledge of SQL. Can anyone suggest how to proceed?

Comment: You may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52306194/aws-automating-queries-in-redshift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short answer: There could be many ways to do it, what you're trying.**

**Long answer:** It could be done any of below mentioned ways in general.

1. Using any general purpose programming language(java, python, C/C++,.net, etc.)
2. Using any ready made [ETL](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/best-etl-tools/) tools(like pantaho, AWS glue etc)
3. Other ways

Since you said, you are naive, I would like to explain you simple approach that I used for complex ETL in my past(i.e. plain shell scripts), though think about your use case and weight it against various options I suggested and use the one fits best to you.

1. Create your shell/batch scripts to run SQL.
2. Setup a cron job to invoke #1 shell script.

Here goes the example shell script to begin with. Make sure to run beow command, `psql` command should be installed on one of your EC2 from where you will be connected to `Redshift`

```
#!/bin/sh
# example comment!
echo "Executing the create sales table"
psql postgresql://username:password@redshift-url:port/databasename?sslmode=require -c 
    "create table sales(    Colunm1 varchar(55),    Colunm2 varchar(255), updated_at timestamp);"
echo "Sales table created."
```

This only provides you some pointers to begin with. There are so many pros/cons of every approach and as I said, you must weight all the pros/cons before deciding any approach.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much for your help, really appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: I have PostgreSQL in under RDS instances, where i am able to create a database, do i have to install PostgreSQL on my system?
or how i will run the cron job? Is there any video available where i can go step by step to reach out the final stage?

Comment: No `psql` is client tool, I believe it could be installed without full PostgreSQL database. Here is some pointer. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/249494/install-postgresql-client-psql-only-on-centos , similarly `crontab` is very popular and old way of scheduling the jobs, I think check your network administrator or anyone bit familiar with `unix`. here you go with basis info on `cron-tab`. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/crontab.htm. for additional info, please search on youtube with cron tab you should get lot of good material to begin with.